# regex not recoginizing matches as True

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe with text data and I'm trying to clean out rows with empty content values. I have one row whose content column looks like this:

```
articles.loc[197040, 'content']
'     '
```

I've tried cleaning it up with .isnull(), but that doesn't recognize empty strings. So I resorted to regex and tried:

```
nothing = re.compile(r'\W{1,}')
articles = articles[articles['content'] != nothing]
```

But this leaves the empty articles in. If I try:

```
'     ' == nothing
```

I get `False`. But the [regex tester](https://regex101.com/) seems to indicate that that should work. Using `r'\W*'` also returns `False`.

The problem persists with other meaningless strings---e.g., a mix of commas and whitespace---when other regex combinations are tried.

Thanks for any help.

#### Edit:

It's also not recognizing equivalence here:

```
'what.' == re.compile(r'\w*\.')
False
```

Or here:

```
'6:45' == r'[^A-Z]{1,}'
False
```

And so on and so forth.

Comment: you don't need regex for this work you can compare `'     '.strip() == ''`

Comment: `\W{1,}` matches any non-word character (equal to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`). Why'd you expect it to work ? :)

Comment: That's a capital W. Lowercase w matches word characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a regex matches a string you have to use the [**match**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) method, not to check for equality. You're basically comparing a string with a pattern object which, of course, are not equal. Try this:

```
nothing.match('    ') # out: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='    '>
x.match(' , , ,') # out: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match=' , , ,'>
```

Comment: This is what I realized literally right after I updated with my last edit, but I didn't want to delete the question (the last answerer got a rep boost from this question) and figured I'd just award whoever came around to post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround the problem using [`isspace`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) built-in, it returns true if there are only whitespace characters in the string and there is at least one character.

---

Demo, also filtering empty strings:

```
import pandas as pd
articles =  pd.DataFrame({'content' : ['foo','bar','   ','foo','    ','']})    
articles = articles[(~articles['content'].str.isspace()) & (articles['content'] != '')]

>>> articles
  content
0     foo
1     bar
3     foo
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful and I upvoted, but I'm still waiting to see if someone can explain why this regex isn't working, as there are lots of strings in this dataframe like `' ,  , , '`that need cleaning.